# Regex matching string if the string is not ending with special characters

Tags: regex

i am not that familiar with REGEX

I want to a match a string which the last character should not be special character.

I have tried this regex:

```
/^[a-z0-9](?!.*?[^\na-z0-9]{2}).*?[a-z0-9]$/
```

but no success.

What regex can i use for this kind of scenario? Thanks.

Comment: oh yeah use this: `/\w$/` or `/[a-zA-Z0-9]$/`

Comment: /[^a-zA-Z0-9]$/ this works but if the string is ending with special character. I want the exact opposite. Thanks

Comment: thanks that works.

Comment: no problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/\w$/` ensures the last char is a word char i.e nothing but `/[a-zA-Z0-9]$/`

Answer (score 1):

If /\w$/ is not working for your (some bizarre regex interpreter perhaps) then...

[a-zA-Z0-9]$
will match strings where the "last character should not be special character"

[^a-zA-Z0-9]$
will match "the exact opposite".